# angularjs checkbox onchange not working in form .$pristine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I have a form in angular and having some input boxes, checkbox and a submit button.Initially Submit button is Disabled.
If I change any element from that form then the submit button become enable. 
I am making use of angularjs feature `.$pristine and $invalid` for that. It is working fine for input boxes but not working for checkbox change.
Am I doing anything wrong? kindly guide me.
See the fiddle :[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qAqe/11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `ng-model` for checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" required />
```

**Working Demo**:http://jsfiddle.net/7qAqe/12/

> "An input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control. The name attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance."
> [- Forms Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Answer (score 0):

You did not bind the checkbox input to any model.
Refer to [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwokdbwz/)

```
<input type="checkbox" required ng-model='rel.checked' />
```